# Mustache / Handlebars / Hogan templates in separate files in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, mustache, hogan.js

I am writing a very simple `node` app that has a `JSON`-API, part of that `JSON` are small bits of `HTML`. To write templates for the `HTML` I would live to use a templating engine like `Mustache`. However, it seems that using `Mustache` I would have to write my entire templates as `string`s and pass those on to `Mustache`. Is it not possible to have a file like `myfile.template.js` that is an actual `Markup` / `Mustache` file that I can import and compile? I would resort to `Jade`, which still is my fallback, but I feel its syntax and would be less readable than `Mustache`'s, given that my use-case is very small templates.

Answer (score 1):

I've put my hogan templates in a file, then read them in with fs and called hogan compile at the start of my script. Ends up looking something like:

```
var doneFile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/templates/html/done.template', 'utf-8');
var doneTemplate = hogan.compile(doneFile);
```

and then later in this example i call:

```
res.send(doneTemplate.render({username: req.body.user}));
```

(the important part being the render call)